# Google maps api: map not consistently executing fitBounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Code in question:

```
function setAllMap(map) {
    console.debug(3);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    resetZoomOnMapEvents(markers);
}
function resetZoomOnMapEvents(nuLoc) {
        console.debug(1);
        var marks = typeof nuLoc == 'undefined' ? nuLoc : markers;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i in marks) {
            bounds.extend(marks[i].position);
        }
        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

The map works correctly on return of search results. It will sometimes center to the center of the map markers but other times it will center on Spain/Africa. Direct question: why is the behavior not consistent?

Comment: Why are you doing both map.setCenter and map.fitBounds?  You should only do one.

Comment: I just took setCenter out. Didn't change a thing...

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by sharing my script(s) it will help trigger something?
I have a loop, that for each position, I call a method called "renderMarker". That method assembles the marker.

I then call the "centerMap" method.

```
var GoogleMaps = {
'map': {},
    'marker': {},
    'markerArray': [],
    'markerlatlngArray': [],

    /**
     * Renders marker(s) to the map.
     * Creates infowindow for the given marker.
     * 
     * @param {object} myobj| data for the given marker.
     * @returns {void}
     * 
     */
    renderMarker: function (myobj) {
        var markerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(myobj.lat, myobj.lng);

        GoogleMaps.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            'position': markerlatlng,
            'map': GoogleMaps.map,
            'title': my_title,
            'icon': 'my-icon.png',
            'animation': google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            'data': '<div class="myobjinfowindow">'
                     '<p>Whatever you want goes here.</p>'
                    + '</div>'
        });

        GoogleMaps.marker.set('propertyA', myobj.propertyA);
        GoogleMaps.marker.set('propertyB', myobj.propertyB);
        GoogleMaps.marker.set('propertyC', myobj.propertyC);

        GoogleMaps.markerlatlngArray.push(markerlatlng);
        GoogleMaps.markerArray.push(GoogleMaps.marker);

        GoogleMaps.centerMap();

        GoogleMaps.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(GoogleMaps.marker, 'click', function () {
            GoogleMaps.infowindow.close();
            GoogleMaps.infowindow.setContent(this.data);
            GoogleMaps.infowindow.open(GoogleMaps.map, this);
        });
    }

/**
 * Centers the map around the given markers.
 * 
 * @returns {void}
 * 
 */
centerMap: function () {
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        $.each(GoogleMaps.markerlatlngArray, function (i, marker) {
            latlngbounds.extend(marker);
        });

        GoogleMaps.map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        GoogleMaps.map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but... ummm... I'm looking at your centerMap function and we're doing the exact same thing except you're using a jquery each function on a marker you've created... my markers position is stored in an index called 'internalPosition'. The zooming to fit just the markers works beautifully. It's just not centering the map on the bounds.getCenter().

Comment: Not that it changes anything, but calling `setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter())` followed by `fitBounds` is redundant.

Comment: If you are looping through something that calls `renderMarker` multiple times, do a `fitBounds` at the end, rather than during, which will result in unnecessary function calls, and probably bizarre behavior to the user.

Answer (score 0):

As given, the question asks very directly: "Why is it that sometimes the map recenters on an area between Spain and Arica?"

First reasonable analysis would suggest making sure that the code provided actually works.

After extensive testing and tracing, the code does work. Part of the difficulty in this is the fact that this is an inherited project and the methods used are called in multiple locations. The difficulty is increased by virtue of the fact that just loading the page launches a search which fires off these same methods and there is no inherited way to determine if the method is called on page load or user interaction. Therein lies the apparent inconsistency: Why would it load correctly 100% of the time on a manual search but not 100% of the time on initial page load search?

To ensure that this is a reasonable question, extensive testing of all modules and pages using the google maps api needed to be completed and observations noted. Indeed, all pages with this feature worked correctly on manual search and all pages but one worked correctly on initial page load search.

This begs the next logical question: is something happening on that *one* page to cause inconsistent behavior?

In the pursuit of an answer, javascript was traced, network responses were analyzed. Network times were not responsible (necessary analysis in case data did not exist by the time a call was completed thereby possibly altering results). The remaining conclusion is that, for some reason, sometimes something would recenter the map either before or after the calls noted in the original question.

After more analysis, a method was discovered that reset the map center to 35, 0 lat/long. This is, incidentally, a location between Spain and Africa. Removing the code which forced this recentering solved the issue.

To summarize, there is nothing wrong per se with the code submitted in the original question. The problem with a deeply "hidden" javascript method that was not readily visible and was not documented.